# Google direction api request invalid in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, google-api, mapkit, google-directions-api

Here is my request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=49.276951,-123.128559&destination=49.277874,-122.912404&mode=transit&sensor=false
The result is:
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}

It worked before, but it does not work when i used it today. why is that?
Note: it works fine when i change it to mode=walking

Comment: Same thing happened to me. This link used to work until today: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&mode=transit&destination=40.742160,-73.987989&origin=40.762940,-73.988520

Comment: then i am sure that its not my problem! thank you Joseph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=49.276951,-123.128559&destination=49.261566,-123.138399&mode=transit&sensor=false&departure_time=1346197500

The above request works. We can solve this problem by adding departure_time parameter since Google may updated the direction api and set departure time as a mandatory parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably that there is no public transit that can take you from your origin to your destination, thus the invalid request..

Comment: Plugging it into google maps shows that there is transit available.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a transit from origin to destination.