# How to set travel mode to “Transit” in google map direction API

Tags: google-maps, directions

We're trying to figure out how to using google map direction API in our application. 
It working well with travel modes like Driving. But it did not showing Transit mode when we entered two places in Japan(which is totally fine in map.google.com).
[No Transit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnJqa.jpg)
[same places in map.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNITb.jpg)

So for using Transit mode what should I do?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction).

`transit_mode` - Specifies one or more preferred modes of transit. This parameter may only be specified for transit directions.

[`transit`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes) - requests directions via public transit routes (*where available*). If you set the mode to transit, you can optionally specify either a departure_time or an arrival_time. If neither time is specified, the departure_time defaults to now (that is, the departure time defaults to the current time). You can also optionally include a transit_mode and/or a transit_routing_preference.

So maybe not all places, the transit mode are available.

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679594/all-google-maps-directions-web-service-api-requests-with-mode-transit-return-inv) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> The Google Maps Directions Service supports all of the transit
>   providers listed in the Transit Coverage List, except for those in
>   Japan.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transit_directions_countries